# Call return type must be parameterized as Call<Foo> or Call<? extends Foo> Exception while calling retrofit API

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

Below are the Dependencies which I have used

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

Below is the code which I am calling retrofit API

```
RequestBody jsonBody = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"),(jsonInput));

            RetrofitAPI cashMemoService = RetrofitAPICLient.getClient().create(RetrofitAPI.class);
            Call<List<CashMemoDetails>> call = cashMemoService.getCashMemoPendingListObj(jsonBody);
```

This is RetrofitAPICLient

```
public static Retrofit getClient(){
        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(newBseURL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }
```

Below is the Interface

```
@POST("GetCashMemoPunchingList")
    Call<List<CashMemoDetails>> getCashMemoPendingListObj(@Body RequestBody userData);
```

Below is the exception which I am getting

```
 2020-10-20 10:59:47.320 27155-27155/ W/com.hpcl.gsa2: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    2020-10-20 10:59:47.335 27155-27155/ W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for interface g.g
   55-27155/ W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
    2020-10-20 10:59:47.336 27155-27155/ W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Call return type must be parameterized as Call<Foo> or Call<? extends Foo>
    2020-10-20 10:59:47.336 27155-27155/ W/System.err:  ... 22 more
```

Please help me on this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19):

This question is quite old but the problem seems to reappear from time to time. I had this error as well using `Gradle 8.2.1` and `com.android.tools.build:gradle 8.0.2` and a downgrade to `com.android.tools.build:gradle 7.4.2` fixed it! But a downgrade is not really a solution, so I investigated a bit further

I was able to fix it by adding some of the Proguard rules from [here](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/tree/master/libraries) (nameley Retrofit and Okhttp rules)

```
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
```

You should also make sure that your retrofit and Okhttp versions are up-to-date and that you follow the proguard / R8 config hints laid out in [the Readme](https://github.com/square/retrofit#r8--proguard)

Comment: It didn't help me, I fixed the problem by downgrading gradle to v7.4.2

Comment: This worked for me, seems like latest version of AGP R8 is actually obfuscating retrofit stuff that is required.

Answer (score 9):

You need not downgrade your Gradle version solely for this purpose. When you update to Gradle 8 (or a version higher than 8), R8 will automatically be enabled in full mode. If you wish to revert to compact mode, simply add the following line to your gradle.properties file:

> android.enableR8.fullMode=false

Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error on Release mode, no errors on Debug mode. Downgrade Gradle from 8.0.0 to 7.4.0 solved my problem.

Comment: I investigated this further and it turns out Gradle is **not** to blame, it's the Android Gradle Build Tools. Gradle 8.2.1 is running fine, as long as I downgrade the `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to 7.4.2!

Answer (score 3):

**Dependencies**

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0"
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.7.2'
```

**Calling Retrofit API**

Get response in ResponseBody and then parse it to List of Object.

```
RetrofitAPI cashMemoService = RetrofitAPICLient.getClient().create(RetrofitAPI.class);
Call<ResponseBody> call = cashMemoService.getCashMemoPendingListObj(jsonBody);
```

**Interface**

```
@POST("GetCashMemoPunchingList")
Call<ResponseBody> getCashMemoPendingListObj(@Body RequestBody userData);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this error too. Everything worked fine except signed APK's with enabled minify.I have fixed it by adding some rules to the proguard-rules.pro file.
In general, for retrofit, you need to add the following rules to proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keepattributes Signature, InnerClasses, EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations, RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations
-keepattributes AnnotationDefault
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn kotlin.Unit
-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions
-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$*
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* <methods>; }
-keep,allowobfuscation interface <1>
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* <methods>; }
-keep,allowobfuscation interface * extends <1>
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* public *** *(...); }
-keep,allowoptimization,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation class <3>
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response
```

Comment: Try many methods, but this works for me. The crash is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error after renaming the package in my project. everything worked fine except signed APK's with enabled minify. I have fixed it by adding this to my proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep class com.yourproject.app.** { *; }
```

I suppose that the problem was in the **last line**. minifier might have been removing my classes because of package name mismatch, which is now prevented.